# Should the exploration rate be updated at the end of the episode or at every step?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, exploration-exploitation-tradeoff, epsilon-greedy-policy

My agent uses an $\epsilon$-greedy strategy to learn. The exploration rate (i.e. $\epsilon$) decays throughout the training. I've seen examples where people update $\epsilon$ every time an action is taken, while others update it at the end of the episode. If updated at every action, $\epsilon$ is more continuous. Does it matter? Is there a standard? Is one better than another?

Comment: In the long run it would make no difference and both have their benefits. Updating after an episode will take longer to converge but offers more exploration and vice-versa.